# how to generate assets for different android screen bucket sizes?

Tags: android, android-assets

I m new to android development, Is there any tool to generate different assets for different screen sizes.

That can be added to drawable folder, for hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi/xxxhdpi

Answer (score 1):

In android studio...
Go to

File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories

Search for "android drawable importer"
and download the plugin.

Once installed, to use the plugin...
Go to

File -> New -> Batch Drawable Import

Here you can browse to the image you want to import and scale them to the different density buckets.

Steps mentioned for Android Studio 2.3.3

Or you can download it from their website.
[link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer) to plugin.